# Makes sense a N:M relationship with foreign and primary keys?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have a CONSUMER entity and a DEVICE entity. There is a N:M relationship CONECTION betwen CONSUMER and DEVICE.

I have a foreign key CONSUMER_EMAIL from CONSUMER and DEVICE_INDEX_ID from DEVICE. CONECTION has a time atribute.

A token is generated and sent to the user so he can be authentified in order to request data.

Does it make sense to have a that two foreign keys and also have a ( device_index_id, time) that allows to differentiate each device as a unique key ?
Sketch of the table:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
-- User [conects from] device relationship N:M     ----------
CREATE TABLE conection (                
    token                               CHAR(64)            NOT NULL,   -- Randomly generated and sent to the user                                  
    consumer_email                      VARCHAR(254)        NOT NULL,               
    device_index_id                     UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT  NOT NULL,               
    time                                TIMESTAMP           NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    FOREIGN KEY (consumer_email)                                                
    FOREIGN KEY (device_index_id)                                                       
    UNIQUE KEY (device_index_id, time)
    PRIMARY KEY (token)                                         
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: what would be the point? do you need to ensure uniqueness of the rows?

Comment: @koriander Well, from the model view, each conection is diferent. So I wanted to reflect it in  the table. Maybe I only need device_index_id and time to identify it.

Comment: you only need a primary key for those 3 fields if you need to ensure there is no garbage data that creates duplicates, or if you need to to searches for exact combinations of these 3 fields. So far, the answer to your question seems to be "no" :)

Comment: @koriander I have updated the answer, please have a look. A unique token is generated for each conection and sent to the user, Also I use a unique key with (device, time) because each conection is different, that means that each conection has a unique device-time combination,,,

Comment: what I sadi before applies to (device_index_id, time). You only need it if you want to search based on this tuple, e.g., to find the token. Or if you need to be sure there are no dupes. It may seem logical to add the constraint unique key, but it also has a cost, namely, inserts on the table will be slower.

Answer (score 1):

A N:M relationship table is simply

```
CREATE TABLE ConsumerDevice (
    consumer_email ... -- PRIMARY KEY for Consumer
    device_index_id ... -- PRIMARY KEY for Device
    PRIMARY KEY(consumer_email, device_index_id)  -- for going one way
    INDEX(      device_index_id, consumer_email)  -- for going the other direction
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Yes, you could add

```
time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

And even have it defaulting to updating to the current time.
Your `token` is unnecessary.
You should not have multiple rows for a given Consumer-Device pair.
The *2* FOREIGN KEYs should be obvious, but why bother?

Use INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE... to create a new row or get the `time` updated in a single step.

Comment: The token is sent to the user so when he request data to the server he will need the token to identify himself.